# How to run async tests in django?

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio

I use async django views and async test cases accordingly. When I run tests separately by one test cases it works okay, but when I run a batch of tests I get error:

RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-139' coro=<AsyncToSync.main_wrap() running at /opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py:353> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py:180]> got Future  attached to a different loop

According to django docs "Django will automatically detect any async def tests and wrap them so they run in their own event loop." So I guess there is some loops conflict?

Maybe anyone knows how to fix this error or any patch how to run many async tests in django?